# Styling CardView groups

Tags: android, android-styles

For a small tool, I have to write an Android app. There are no requirements on portability, it's sufficient when the app only runs on android version 6 or later.

I would love to group dialog elements into CardViews and I would love to have some reasonable layout (spacing, colors, etc). Is there a way to use a theme, standard layout, style, etc. that I could use without the need to apply "android:padding", "card_view:cardElevation", ect. attribute to every CardView?

If it's not possible to use some already existing defaults, I could use styles. When I use styles (following Google's "Styles and Themes" API Guide), I get error messages, when I move some attributes from the CardView definition from the layout xml to the style xml. For attributes that I move to the style xml, that begin with "android:", there is no error. For other attributes, I get an `No resource found that matches the given name-error.

```
<style name="CardGroups">
    <item name="xmlns:card_view">"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"</item>
    <item name="card_view:cardElevation">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

results in: `Error:(20, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'card_view:cardElevation'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that styles are the way to go to provide a common set of attributes to multiple Views.

You should not use custom namespaces in your style definitions. For custom attributes provided by libraries (such as `cardElevation`), you simply do not provide a namespace.

Thus your style should look like this:

```
<style name="CardGroups">
    <item name="cardElevation">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you Tanis! I guess the "xmlns:card_view" is something special, that I can left out?

Comment: That is the namespace declaration- since you aren't using the namespace, you don't need the declaration either.